# Let's Encrypt on AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, flask, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, lets-encrypt

I have a Flask application on AWS Elastic Beanstalk. My app is running on Apache on Amazon Linux 2.

I have been attempting to install SSL certificates via Let's Encrypt for several days with very little success. My question is: How can these certificates be installed for a Flask application on AL2?

One of the biggest issues that I am having is that nothing seems to be configured correctly with certbot-auto. I am willing to do any sort of programming and rewriting to get these things to work.

What is the DocumentRoot of my application? I upload a folder to the server with the basic tree:

```
example.org
 L app
 | L templates
 | L __init__.py 
 |
 L application.py
```

It seems that the DocumentRoot ought to be `/example.org/app` but that sends the user to a page that says `Index of /`.

I have followed many tutorials and none of them lead to a correct configuration. The last configuration that I tried cannot even find the certificates! I assume that this is not an uncommon issue for those who have setups similar to mine.

If it is less of a headache to use Nginx, I will consider that option, but I hope that we can find a solution rather than just sidestep the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You could use .ebextension to setup certbot. Have a look at the AWS documentation for this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebextensions.html